# unity c# delegate getting local parameter wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, closures

**Update :**

**The problem was not relevant to this question, but the transparent triggering area of UI Buttons overlapped. The question itself should be closed.**

A `for` loop add N -on click listener to some buttons.

When clicked , the param expected to be 'n' for example, but sometimes become 'n+1'.

In other words, it is expected when button number 'n' is clicked, 'n' is passed as param to the delegate. But actually it become 'n+1' passed as param sometimes.

I heard that the anonymous function should copy the param to a local variable.
I have done it all the way to the delegate. But it didn't help.

```
public class StageMenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
...
public Button stageTemplate;
void Start()
{
// get stage count
numberOfStages = SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings;

Transform container = stageTemplate.transform.parent;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStages; i++){

    Button stage = Object.Instantiate(stageTemplate, container);
    ...
    // stage number on the icon
    int j = i+1;

    stage.transform.Find("stageNumber")
    .gameObject.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text 
    = (j).ToString("D2");

    ...
    int m = j;

    bool addTheListener(int k){
            int m = k;
            Debug.Log("AddListener scene " +m);
            stage.onClick.AddListener(delegate(){
                int n = m;
                Debug.Log("go to scene " +n);
                UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(n);
            });
            return true;
    }
    var x = addTheListener(j);
}
...
}
```

Comment: You're adding `numberOfStages` listeners to a single `stage` `Button`?

Comment: Sounds like a closure problem, but the code you've provided doesn't like like it should happen. (You shouldn't need `m` or `n`, either: `j` is already in local scope).

Comment: @Ruzihm I suspect that `stage` is an instantiated object, but yes, we can't see where it was declared.

Comment: Please include enough code to produce a [mre]. Voting to close until then.

Comment: @Ruzihm , N stages , N-stage-buttons , going to each stages!

Comment: @Draco18s , sorry , i missed it ! "stage" is cloned gameObject in each loop